# "Failed to load elasticsearch nodes" in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, groovy, spring-batch

I have a Groovy application that connects to elasticsearch via Spring Data and Spring Boot. When i start the application always raise this exception failed to load elasticsearch nodes: org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available.

> I’ve tried on elasticsearch 6.4.0 and spring-data-elasticsearch
>   3.1.10.

**ESConfig.groovy**

```
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "RepositoryEs")
class ESConfig {

    @Bean
    TransportClient client5() throws Exception{
        Settings settings = Settings.builder()
                .put("cluster.name", "elasticsearch")
                .build()
        TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings)
        client.addTransportAddress(new TransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("172.17.0.2"), 9300))
        return client
    }

    @Bean
    ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate2() throws Exception {
        return new ElasticsearchTemplate(client5())
    }
}
```

**build.gradle**

```
    compile group: 'org.springframework.batch', name: 'spring-batch-infrastructure', version: '4.1.2.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-elasticsearch', version: '3.1.10.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.elasticsearch', name: 'elasticsearch', version: '6.4.0'
    compile group: 'org.elasticsearch.client', name: 'transport', version: '6.4.0'
    compile group: 'org.elasticsearch.client', name: 'elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client', version: '6.4.0'
```

**Error**

```
.d.e.r.s.AbstractElasticsearchRepository : failed to load elasticsearch nodes : org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{2sKiemzqQF2aaIi0f28pDg}{172.17.0.2}{172.17.0.2:9300}]
```

*Here is elasticsearch's info:*

```
{
  "name" : "Vapor",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "9jDgrlPmT4yH2lldlo2tUA",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "2.4.1",
    "build_hash" : "c67dc32e24162035d18d6fe1e952c4cbcbe79d16",
    "build_timestamp" : "2016-09-27T18:57:55Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "5.5.2"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

```
{
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "status" : "yellow",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 1,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 1,
  "active_primary_shards" : 10,
  "active_shards" : 10,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 10,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0,
  "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis" : 0,
  "active_shards_percent_as_number" : 50.0
}
```

Why i am getting error? Is there any other property should i use?

Comment: It's it running on IP 172.17.0.2?

Comment: yes,``` $ curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_nodes/_all/version?pretty='
{
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "nodes" : {
    "_bT85q20TQCZfXFYNjD7mA" : {
      "name" : "Vapor",
      "transport_address" : "172.17.0.2:9300",
      "host" : "172.17.0.2",
      "ip" : "172.17.0.2",
      "version" : "2.4.1",
      "build" : "c67dc32",
      "http_address" : "172.17.0.2:9200"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do the elasticsearch logs show this is working? 172 feels odd.. is this running in docker? Have you set `network.host` in your es config?

Comment: @tim_yates, yes, it running in docker, {
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "status" : "yellow",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 1,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 1,
  "active_primary_shards" : 10,
  "active_shards" : 10,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 10,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0,
  "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis" : 0,
  "active_shards_percent_as_number" : 50.0
}

Comment: So if you're running es in docker and the node in docker, then 172.x.x.x is probably the docker networking address, which is unreachable from outside docker https://www.elastic.co/blog/docker-networking